# decompose() always returns 'bound method Tag.decompose of <strong></strong>'. Python, BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In the documentation BeautifulSoup I found information to removed tag is used '[decompose()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose)', but whenever I try to apply it in my situation I always get the same result:

```
<bound method Tag.decompose of <strong>1 L</strong>>
```

my goal is to get only '3,78zł / l'. How can I get the correct result using this method?

**My file.py:**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = "https://www.auchandirect.pl/auchan-warszawa/pl/pepsi-cola-max-niskokaloryczny-napoj-gazowany-o-smaku-cola/p-98502176"
r = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'}, timeout=15)
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
type(soup)



products_links_price = soup.find(class_='packaging')


print(products_links_price.strong.decompose)
```

**Result:**

```
<bound method Tag.decompose of <strong>1 L</strong>>
```

When I try to do it the other way (getting a word in 'strong tag' everything works well).

```
print(products_links_price.strong.text)
```

**Result_1**

```
'1 L'
```

Comment: do you not simply need to do decompose() instead of decompose?

Comment: use of this 'print(products_links_price.strong.decompose())' causes returns only 'None' (nothing more)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get only `'3,78zł / l'` as a result, replace `print(products_links_price.strong.decompose)` with:

```
products_links_price.strong.decompose()
print(products_links_price.text.strip())
```

This outputs:

```
3,78zł / l
```

Whenever you are trying to print the result of a method or function call and you get `None` you should ask yourself if that method or function specifies a return value. If not, then it will return None by default, as is the case with `decompose()`, since all it does is [recursively destroy the Tag and remove it from the Tag tree](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose):

```
def decompose(self):
    """Recursively destroys the contents of this tree."""
    self.extract()
    i = self
    while i is not None:
        next = i.next_element
        i.__dict__.clear()
        i.contents = []
        i = next
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously `decompose()` method will not return anything as per BeautifulSoup documentation. You have to select the `p` element which contains `strong` element. After that decompose the `strong` tag from selected element. Now the components of the `strong` tag would have gone and you can extract the text you needed.

```
pack = soup.find('p', class_='packaging')
pack.strong.decompose()
print(pack.text) # this will return the desired output 3,78zł / l
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!